# In Selenium with python, after choosing drop down option page refresh but giving values of previous page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I choose the next page from the drop-down, the page refreshes when I choose values by python program it gives me the value of the previous page. Though the same query on firebug reaches the correct values but python program unable to fetch values in the new page.

```
<tr>
<td headers="SINCE">18-FEB-16</td>
<td headers="TOKEN">
<span style="font-family:mono,new courier;font-size:14;color:darkgreen;font- weight:bold">vavFeth3</span>
</td>
<td headers="STATUS">
```

Comment: Post the python code that you are using.

Comment: I think you should wait for some time for the new value to be displayed (AJAX calls, script etc) and then query the page using findElement

Comment: Yes, increasing the timeout fixed the issue. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

First I fetched values of first page in fetched_passwd then went to next page and then tried to fetch values of next page in fetched_passwd1 but still previous values are being store.

```
fetched_passwd=browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@headers='TOKEN']//following::span[2]")
sum=0
for i in fetched_passwd :
    print(i.text)
    sum=sum+1
    if(sum==9):
        break


next_page=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='X01_5011970802493527']//following::option[1]").click()

fetched_passwd1=browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@headers='TOKEN']//following::span[2]")
sum=0
for j in fetched_passwd1 :
    print(j.text)
    sum=sum+1
    if(sum==10):
        break
```

Comment: Can anybody help me on the above scenario ?